# How to run a sequence of queries against an Access database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to create and run a list of predefined queries on several similar databases.

The idea is open the database, run the queries, and then close.
Now I create each of them manually, run and then delete them from each database.

I don't know how to do it in VBA code.
Can anyone drop me a line on how to do it with a simple example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Name` property for each item in your database's `QueryDefs` collection to make a list of your saved queries.  I think that addresses the title of your question.  However the body of your question seems to ask for a lot more as far as I can tell.

You can load a string variable with the text from the `SQL` property of a `QueryDef` in your current database.  Then use the `OpenDatabase` method to open another db file, and `Execute` that string there.

```
Public Sub RunQueryOnAnotherDb(ByVal pQuery As String, _
        ByVal pRemoteDb As String)

    Dim dbRemote As DAO.Database
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(pQuery).SQL
    'Debug.Print strSql
    Set dbRemote = OpenDatabase(pRemoteDb)
    dbRemote.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    Debug.Print "RecordsAffected: " & dbRemote.RecordsAffected
    dbRemote.Close
    Set dbRemote = Nothing
End Sub
```

There's plenty of room to refine that one.  You should add error handling for example.  But, though quick & dirty, I hope it points you in a useful direction.

I tested it on my system like this, and it works with my db and query names.

```
Public Sub test_RunQueryOnAnotherDb()
    Const cstrQuery As String = "qryTestDelete"
    Const cstrRemoteDb As String = "C:\share\Access\0NewScratch.mdb"
    RunQueryOnAnotherDb cstrQuery, cstrRemoteDb
End Sub
```